# Better way to solve my class hierarchy problem than Unsafe.As cast to a child class?

Tags: c#, oop

(I'm writing about matrices, but don't worry, this is not a maths question and presumes no maths knowledge.)

I have a `Matrix` class that has three fields

```
double[] Data;
int Rows;
int Columns;
```

and defines hundreds of mathematical operations.

Additionally, I have a `SymmetricMatrix : Matrix` subclass that has no instance fields of its own, that offers all of the operations above via inheritance, offers some additional operations (like EigenvalueDecomposition), *and finally* repeats *some* definitions with a `new` keyword to change the return type to `SymmetricMatrix`.

For example, if `Matrix` has

```
public Matrix MatrixMultiplication(Matrix otherMatrix)
public Matrix ScaledBy(double scalar)
```

then  `SymmetricMatrix` would simply inherit the `MatrixMultiplication` but it would change the `ScaledBy` to return a `SymmetricMatrix`.

Rather than reimplementing `ScaledBy` , I define it via

```
// SymmetricMatrix.cs
public new SymmetricMatrix ScaledBy(double scalar) => base.ScaledBy(scalar).AsSymmetricMatrix()
// Matrix.cs
public SymmetricMatrix AsSymmetricMatrix() => Unsafe.As<SymmetricMatrix>()
```

(I'm using `new` instead of `virtual+override` for reasons that don't matter for the purposes of this question).

I found this approach to work surprisingly well, and it allows me to be super succinct in defining `SymmetricMatrix.cs`. The obvious downside is that it may exploit unsupported behavior (?) and that it confuses the debugger I'm using a lot (the runtime type of the result of the cast is `Matrix` which is not a subclass of its compile time type `SymmetricMatrix`, and yet, all the operations defined on `SymmetricMatrix` succeed because the data held by both classes is the same)

**Questions**

1. Do you foresee any problems with my approach that I haven't though of?
2. Might my approach break with the next dotnet version?
3. Do you think there are cleaner ways of achieving what I want? I had a few ideas but none seem to work out cleanly. For example, I cannot encode which operations preserve Child classes in the parent class via

```
class Matrix<T> where T : Matrix
...
T ScaledBy(double other)
```

because whether or not an operation preserves a Child class is knowledge only the Child can have. For example, `SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix` would NOT be preserved by `ScaledBy`.

Alternatively, I could use encapsulation over inheritance and define

```
class BaseMatrix
{
    ...lots of operations
}
...
class Matrix : BaseMatrix
{
    private BaseMatrix _baseMatrix;
    ...lots of "OperationX => new Matrix(_baseMatrix.OperationX)"
}
class SymmetricMatrix : BaseMatrix
{
    private BaseMatrix _baseMatrix;
    ...lots of "OperationX => preserving ? new SymmetricMatrix(_baseMatrix.OperationX) : new Matrix(_baseMatrix.OperationX);"
}
```

That's very sad to code up though, because I'd have to manually propagate every change I make to `BaseMatrix` to, at the moment, four extra classes, and users would have to manually cast `SymmetricMatrix`s to `Matrix` in lots of scenarios.

Finally, I could simply not offer subclasses and rather have flags like `bool _isSymmetric` and encode the operations that preserve symmetry/positivity/... by changing/setting the flags in all my methods. This is sad too, because :

1. Users would then be able to write `Matrix.EigenvalueDecomposition()` just to have this break at runtime with a `You have to promise me that your matrix is symmetric because I only implemented EigenvalueDecomposition for that case` error
2. It would be too easy to forget resetting a flag when it's not preserved and then accidentally running an operation that assumes symmetry (which BLAS does by simply ignoring half of the matrix)
3. I like being able to specify in the type system rather than the comments that, e.g., the matrix I return from `CholeskyFactor` is lower triangular (conventions differ and some may expect an upper triangular matrix)
4. Users wouldn't see which flags are currently set so they wouldn't know whether I use the "specialized" version of a given algorithm and likely end up using `.SetSymmetric()` unnecessarily all over the place just to be safe.

Comment: Can you please share the `ScaleBy` method implementation?

Comment: How about having your base class being an abstract generic ? Could work well enough for your purposes

Comment: You've basically replaced runtime typing with compile time typing. As long as you stay on the compile time, it's fine. However, that's very C, C# wasn't really meant for that. What you're trying to do is to change object type at runtime, aka "transmutation". This seems to be relevant: https://blog.tchatzigiannakis.com/changing-an-objects-type-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Does `ScaledBy()` return a scaled copy, or does it scale the original and return it?

Comment: @GuruStron it's `ScaledBy` (relevant as per Matthew's question) and it's essentially `var output = new double[Data.Length]; BLAS.axpy(scalar, Data, output);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson a scaled copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we were talking with colleagues about procedural programming, here's my 2 cents about your problem.
The underlying data structure is of (and keep its) specific form:

```
struct DataMatrix
{
    public double[] Data;
    public int Rows;
    public int Columns;
}
```

As you have specific behaviour depending on the type, you can flag it in a specialized type instead of strong-typing it:

```cs
struct Matrix
{
    public DataMatrix DataMatrix;
    public bool isSymmetrical;
    public bool isDefinite;
    public bool isUpperTriangular;
}
```

Then, you may call your methods from one place using said flagged type:

```cs
// MatrixManager acts solely as a namespace for convenient method grouping
public static class MatrixManager
{
    //Consider a void return for each method, as matrix.DataMatrix is(/may be) the only affected field

    public static Matrix Multiplication(Matrix matrix, Matrix otherMatrix) => /*..multiply matrix.DataMatrix with otherMatrix.DataMatrix then return matrix.*/;
    public static Matrix ScaledBy(Matrix matrix, double scalar) => /*..scale matrix.DataMatrix with scalar then return matrix.*/;
    public static void SetSymmetrical(Matrix matrix) { if (!matrix.isSymmetrical) matrix.isSymmetrical = true; }

    public static Matrix UnavailableOperationIfSymmetricalExample(Matrix matrix) => matrix.isSymmetrical ? matrix : EigenvalueDecomposition(matrix);
    /*..hundreds of Matrix-based methods here..*/
    public static Matrix EigenvalueDecomposition(Matrix matrix) { if (matrix.isSymmetrical) return matrix; /*..otherwise do decompose matrix.DataMatrix then return matrix.*/}
}
```

This way, you can specify the actual behaviour when calling a method with any flagged `Matrix` type (throw exception? call another method? return?), without having to bother with a behaviour-type tangled structure.

Hope that would suit your needs.

Comment: I do like the idea of using flags to specify the matrix properties. But the one way where they fall behind is allowing checks during compilation that a given method can be called on a given matrix. Oh, we could imagine a solution based on Attributes and a Roslyn code analyzer. But that seems less intuitive.

Comment: The type-safety was not reliably enforced with `Unsafe.As`, and that's why I also like your generics: they force type-behavior safety at compile time. (Not a big fan of mixing type and behaviour tho, hence my answer!)

Comment: I don't think compile-time checks are well suited for functionnal checks. Per the op, the methods are all based on a (unsafed-)derivation of the `Matrix` type, so there's no technical benefit to compile against a derived type (it's a use-case problem, not a compilation question). There's a development benefit in calling the same method's name with a different type leading to a different outcome (easier per-type method readability) but that comes with the cost of type-tanglement, behaviour-based inheritance, and lots of overrides. In pure-OOP, I think generics are great tho.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like the pure-data class idea, dislike the static functionality idea. I added an answer with what I ended up with, if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I missed a requirement, you could implement what you want using generics

A (not so brief) example :

```cs
public abstract class BaseMatrix<TMatrix> where TMatrix : BaseMatrix<TMatrix>
{
    // Replace with how you actuallt are storing you matrix values
    protected object _valueStore;

    // common initialization (if required), if not keep empty
    protected BaseMatrix()
    {

    }

    // necessary to copy the value store.
    protected BaseMatrix(object valueStore)
    {
        this._valueStore = valueStore;
    }

    public virtual TMatrix ScaledBy(double scalar) 
    {
        // implementation
        return default;
    }
}

public class Matrix : BaseMatrix<Matrix>
{

}

public class SymmetricMatrix : BaseMatrix<SymmetricMatrix>
{
    public SymmetricMatrix() : base(){}

    // allows to build from another matrix, could be internal
    public SymmetricMatrix(object valueStore) : base(valueStore){}

    public override SymmetricMatrix ScaledBy(double scalar)
    {
        return base.ScaledBy(scalar);
    }
}

public class SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix : BaseMatrix<SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix> 
{
    // If we *know* the type is not the same after this method call, we mask with a new one retirning the target type
    // A custom cast operator will handle the conversion
    public new SymmetricMatrix ScaledBy(double scalar)
    {
        return base.ScaledBy(scalar);
    }

    // Added to allow a cast between SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix  and SymmetricMatrix
    // in this example, we keep the value store to not have to copy all the values
    // Depending on project rules could be explicit instead
    public static implicit operator SymmetricMatrix(SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix positiveSymmetricMatrix)
    {
        return new SymmetricMatrix(positiveSymmetricMatrix._valueStore);
    }
}
```

Which would make the `ScaledBy(double)` method available in each type of matrix, and returning the type of the matrix it was called on.

And it would comply with your requirement not to have to redefine most methods / properties in each class.

Obviously, you can override methods in childrens to either do more before or after the `base()` call or even define an entirely different implementation.

One shortcoming would be if you needed one type to inherit from a class inheriting from `BaseMatrix<TMatrix>`. You'd have no way of changing the generic type parameter.

Alternatively if this really doesn't match your needs and prefer to go the encapsulation route, you could have a look at [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) since the code seems to be quite repetitive.

Comment: I think this works. Weirdly, I had my current "opt into preservation in the child classes" approach, and I looked at "make everything preserving via generics" approach, but I didn't connect the two to "make everything preserving via generics by default and opt OUT of in the child classes".

Comment: Ah except for the caveat you mention: Ideally, I'd like for `SymmetricPositiveDefinite` to inherit from `Symmetric`.

Comment: @Bananach Yeah, that's the only drawback of my solution. You could always declare an intermediate `BaseSymmetric<TMatrix>` which would inherit from `BaseMatrix<TMatrix>` and bineing inherited by `SymmetricMatrix` without any more specialization, and by `SymmetricPositiveDefinite` which would allow to define the generic parameter as you'd want. But that seems overly "verbose" (for lack of a better word) for such a simple task

Comment: I ended up with a non-generic solution. I didn't like having to opt-out of "preservation" because it's not tragic to accidentally use the base method on a child, but it's not safe to use a child method when you should be using the parent method. See my answer if you're interested

Comment: I ended up accepting someone else's answer just because they have less reputation than you even though yours came first, I hope you forgive ;)

Comment: @Bananach No worries, though you should probably accept your own answer since that's what ultimately solved your problem. (Just so people that find this question in the future know easily what you went with)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the use of `Unsafe.As()` is indeed unsafe.

A major problem is this:

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix(/* whatever */);
SymmetricMatrix smat = mat.AsSymmetricMatrix();
Console.WriteLine(smat.GetType().FullName); // "Matrix"
```

So you have something declared as `SymmetrixMatrix` but its underlying type is in fact `Matrix`. I'm sure you can imagine the sort of horrible problems that could cause...

This approach also requires that the base class knows about its derived classes - a big no-no.

One way to solve issues like this it to make sure you can clone your objects in a way that works with inheritance. Then you can clone the original objects and return them, with a cast if necessary.

For example:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public Matrix()
    {
        // Whatever
    }

    // Copy constructor; used for cloning.
    public Matrix(Matrix other)
    {
        _data = other._data.ToArray();
    }

    public virtual Matrix ScaledBy(double scalar)
    {
        var result = Clone();
        result.ScaleBy(scalar);
        return result;
    }

    protected void ScaleBy(double scalar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _data.Length; ++i)
        {
            _data[i] *= scalar;
        }
    }

    protected virtual Matrix Clone()
    {
        return new Matrix(this);
    }

    readonly double[] _data = new double[16]; // For illustration.
}

public class SymmetricMatrix: Matrix
{
    public SymmetricMatrix()
    {
        // Whatever
    }

    // Copy constructor; used for cloning.
    public SymmetricMatrix(SymmetricMatrix other): base(other)
    {
        // No new fields to copy.
        // Any newly added fields should be copied here.
    }

    public override SymmetricMatrix ScaledBy(double scalar)
    {
        // This cast will work because the underlying type returned from 
        // base.ScaledBy() really is SymmetricMatrix
        return (SymmetricMatrix)base.ScaledBy(scalar);
    }

    protected override SymmetricMatrix Clone()
    {
        return new SymmetricMatrix(this);
    }
}

public class SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix: Matrix
{
    // Doesn't override ScaledBy() so SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix.ScaledBy() will return a Matrix.

    protected override SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix Clone()
    {
        // If SymmetricMatrix ever adds new fields to be cloned, they should be cloned here.
        return Unsafe.As<SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix>(base.Clone());
    }
}
```

Now code like this returns the expected types:

```
var smatrix = new SymmetricMatrix();
var sresult = smatrix.ScaledBy(1.0);

Console.WriteLine(sresult.GetType().FullName); // "SymmetricMatrix"

var spmatrix = new SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix();
var spresult = spmatrix.ScaledBy(1.0);

Console.WriteLine(spresult.GetType().FullName); // "Matrix"
```

---

As an example of code where `Unsafe.As()` can cause strange results, consider this code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myBase = new MyBaseClass();
        var pretendDerived = myBase.AsMyDerivedClass();

        // Given the definition of MyDerivedClass, what do you think this will print?
        Console.WriteLine(pretendDerived.Name());
    }
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass AsMyDerivedClass() => Unsafe.As<MyDerivedClass>(this);
}

public class MyDerivedClass
{
    readonly string _name = "TEST";
    public string Name() => _name;
}
```

As [the documentation for `Unsafe.As()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as?view=net-7.0) states:

> The behavior of Unsafe.As(o) is only well-defined if the typical
> "safe" casting operation (T)o would have succeeded. Use of this API to
> circumvent casts that would otherwise have failed is unsupported and
> could result in runtime instability.

Comment: "So you have something declared as SymmetrixMatrix but its underlying type is in fact Matrix. I'm sure you can imagine the sort of horrible problems that could cause..." I asked exactly because even though it feels bad I coudln't come up with actual problems

Comment: "This approach also requires that the base class knows about its derived classes - a big no-no." -- not really, I really wrote this: `public T As<T>() where T : Matrix => Unsafe.As<T>(this);`

Comment: but I get your actual point and I'll see if it works out for me. I want the result of `AsX` to point to the same array, but it seems that's an easy change to your solution

Comment: @Bananach I've added an example showing a sample problem with `Unsafe.As()`. Your code might currently not have any such issue, but IMO it would be an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I did end giving up on `Unsafe.As` and eded up with a solution more similar to yours, except that I created a data-only internal class that I use to do shallow-cloning, see my answer if you're interested

Comment: I ended up accepting someone else's answer just because they have less reputation than you even though yours is more elaborate, I hope you forgive ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the creative answers, all of which I drew inspiration from.
I ended up combining encapsulation and inheritance, using a data-only `TwoDimensionalArray` and inheritance from a method-only (plus a single `TwoDimensionalArray` field) `Matrix` class:

```
class TwoDimensionalArray
{
    double[] data;
    int Rows;
    int Columns
    double Scale;
}

class Matrix
{
    internal readonly TwoDimensionalArray _array;
    public int Rows => _array.Rows;
    public int Columns => _array.Columns;

    public static Ones(int Rows, int Columns)
    {
        var data = new double[Rows * Column];
        data.AsSpan().Fill(1);
        return new Matrix(data, Rows, Columns, 1);
    }

    internal Matrix(TwoDimensionalArray array)
    {
        _array = array;
    }

    public Matrix ScaledBy(double scalar)
    {
        var output = Clone();
        output.ScaleBy(scalar);
        return output;
    }

    public void ScaleBy(double scalar)
    {
        _array.Scale *= scalar;
    }

    public Matrix Clone()
    { 
        var newData = new double[array.data.Length];
        array.data.AsSpan().CopyTo(newData);
        return new Matrix(new TwoDimensionalArray(newData, Rows, Columns);
    }
}

public class SymmetricMatrix : Matrix 
{ 
    internal SymmetricMatrix(TwoDimensionalArray array) => base(array);

    public new SymmetricMatrix ScaledBy(double scalar) => base.ScaledBy(scalar).AsSymmetricMatrix();


    public (Matrix, double[]) EigenvalueDecomposition()
    {
        //implementation
    }
    
    public new SymmetricMatrix Clone() => base.Clone().AsSymmetricMatrix();
}

class SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix : SymmetricMatrix
{
    internal SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix(TwoDimensionalArray array) => base(array);

    public Matrix CholeskyFactor()
    {
        //implementation
    }
 
    public new SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix Clone() => base.Clone().AsSymmetricMatrix();
}

public static class MatrixExt 
{
    public SymmetricMatrix AsSymmetricMatrix(this Matrix matrix)
    {
        return new SymmetricMatrix(matrix._array);
    }

    public SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix AsSymmetricMatrix(this Matrix matrix)
    {
        return new SymmetricPositiveDefiniteMatrix(matrix._array);
    }
}
```

Note that the result of `.AsSymmetricMatrix()` is a view, not a clone (similar to, e.g., `myArray.AsSpan()` being a view of an array, not a copy). I needed `TwoDimensionalArray` to be a class, not a struct, so that *all* changes to the view, including rescaling and reshaping, are reflected in the original.